# PHP session variables not accessable after refresh

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I got a logical problem with this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['username'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != "") {
        $_SESSION["user"] = new User();
        $_SESSION["user"]->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }
}
?>
```

But after refreshing the page , the session is empty.
Does somone know why the session could be empty? The login function is working correctly (tested it with fixed login data at every reload of the page).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you use `session_start` anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing an object in the session, you need to make sure that the class is defined (or available in an autoloader) **before** session_start() is called, otherwise PHP won't be able to deserialise the object.

See http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Probably You have forgotten to start session,
add

```
session_start();
```

before using any Session Variables.

Comment: I didn't forgot this line, it's at the top of the document

Comment: Maybe Somewhere in your code is destroying the session just debug it.

Comment: Already looked for session_destroy(), but i had never used it.

Comment: Can You Put `print_r($_SESSION)` just below `session_start();` and also at the end to verify if every thing is alright within the code

Answer (score 0):

You MUST use `session_start();` at the very first in every file, where you want to access the `$_SESSION` variable. Else it won't work because PHP won't initialize the session itself.

You should write it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

//your code ;)

?>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I dind't forgot this line :/

Comment: How does your login form look like?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Benutzername</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Passwort</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="login" name="submit" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>`  This is my login form

Comment: Could you please try to remove the second closing bracket for the first if-statement in line 2 and retest it again?

Comment: This is not true: included files do not need their own session_start(). You need one session_start() at the beginning, for each request.

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet OP didn't ask about included files here. Sure you don't need to do `session_start();` in every file which is included. PHP will also give errors/warnings when you do that.